# jq: How can a nested object be sliced to include the parent-key hierarchy?

Tags: json, bash, nested, jq

Using Bash and jq, if I have a Bash variable filter **F** of the form `.<key1>.<key2>...<keyN>` and I want to slice a Bash variable JSON object **O** so that the result is just that slice of the object including all keys in **F**, how can this be done with jq?

For example, suppose:

```
O='
{
   "a":
   {
      "b":
      {
         "c": { "p":1 },
         "x": 1
      },
      "x": 2
  },
  "x": 3
}'
```

Then, doing:

```
F='.a.b.c'; jq -r "$F" <<<"$O"
```

results in:

```
{
   "p": 1
}
```

But, I want the slice to include parent key hierarchy.

**Inelegant Solution**

I have come up with a solution, but it involves 2 calls to jq:

```
F='.a.b.c'; S="$(jq -r "$F" <<<"$O"); jq --null-input -r "$F |= $S"
```

that results in:

```
{
  "a": {
    "b": {
      "c": {
        "p": 1
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The solution must work for ***any*** valid **O** and **F** Bash variable where **O** stores a JSON object and **F** is a simple filter of key names only as described above. For example:

```
F='.a.b'; S="$(jq -r "$F" <<<"$O")"; jq --null-input -r "$F |= $S"
```

results in:

```
{
  "a": {
    "b": {
      "c": {
        "p": 1
      },
      "x": 1
    }
  }
}
```

Can slicing an object with a key-hierarchy filter be done more simply in jq?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Provided $F is a valid jq path expression (i.e., so that `jq -n "$F"` works):

```
jq "$F as \$v | null | $F |= \$v" <<< "$O"
```

(I included the |= from your solution to show the similarity, but here you could drop the |.)

Comment: Is the above the same as doing `jq "$F as \$v | {} | $F |= \$v" <<<"$O"`? Otherwise, can you tell me what your solution thoughts were as you crafted the solution? I've tested it and it does, of course, work. Thanks.

Comment: I wanted to show how close you came to the one-step solution. It often helps to think in terms of getpath and setpath.

Comment: Indeed, thanks for that comment. Upvoting and will mark the solution. Thanks again and as always.